# SVNKIT - Get SvnStatusSummary of the working copy

Tags: java, svnkit

I have a working copy organized like this :

Project A
          .svn
          Directory 1
          Direcorty 2
          File A
          File B

I would like to use SvnGetStatusSummary to check if the directory 'Project A' is modified.

This is my code for now :

```
            SvnOperationFactory operationFactory=connection.getOurClientManager().getWcClient().getOperationsFactory();

            SvnGetStatusSummary svnGetStatusSummary=operationFactory.createGetStatusSummary();


            svnGetStatusSummary.setDepth(SVNDepth.INFINITY);

            SvnTarget target=SvnTarget.fromFile(new File("Project A"));

            svnGetStatusSummary.setSingleTarget(target);


            try {
                SvnStatusSummary svnSummary= svnGetStatusSummary.run();

                System.out.println("********************** "+svnSummary.isModified());

            } catch (SVNException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Even if  a file is modified, svnSummary.isModified() always returns false.

If someone can help me, I would appreciate.

Thx